# C++: Can you have a static and a non-static instance of the same class when using the Singleton design pattern?

Tags: c++, class, static, singleton

I'm trying to understand what's happening under the hood with the following piece of code. The question that I'm having trouble with is: How are static instances of classes handled in c++?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Shape {
   public:

      static Shape& getInstance() {
         static Shape obj;
         static Shape& objRef = obj;
         return objRef;
      }

      void init() {
          Shape singleton = Shape::getInstance();
          srand((unsigned)time(0));
          singleton.width = rand()%100;
          singleton.printWidth();
      }

      void printWidth(){
        cout<<width<<endl;
      }
      
   protected:
      int width = 0;
};

int main()
{
   Shape rectangle;
   rectangle.init();
   rectangle.printWidth();
   
   return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
37
0
```

But to me, this doesn't make sense. If a static instance of Shape is made anywhere within the program, shouldn't there only be one Shape in memory? If any shapes call `printWidth` after the singleton has set the width, shouldn't their width be equal to that width?

I would appreciate an explanation of where my thinking is going wrong.

Comment: Your `shape` class is not a singleton.  A singleton has private constructors so only the `get_instance` function can give you a handle to the single object.

Comment: `getInstance` returns a copy, not a reference. The logic in it is also odd. You might read through [C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern) for some information about how to implement this correctly.

Comment: " shouldn't there only be one Shape in memory?" not sure why you think so. First line in main creates an instance, there is the static one in `getInstance` and you make a copy of that in `init`

Comment: `static Shape obj;` <--- this is the instance that exists once in memory no matter how often the function gets called.

Comment: More than one instance of a singleton is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: I suggest you to write a constructor `Shape() { std::cout << "Hello WOrld"; }` and a destructor `~Shape() { std::cout << "Bye!"; }` to get a better idea of how many instances there are created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singleton, by definition, means that you'll have only one instance.

However, `static` does not ensure it's singleton. Your code's `getInstance()` would like to be a common instance getter pattern: you have access to a common instance, but you can also create (arbitrary many) instances as required. So your local instance, `rectangle`, won't be the one that `init()` initializes. What's even worse, in your code, you returns a *copy of* the common instance, not a reference to it (e.g. `static Shape& getInstance()` would solve this), so you have 3 instances we're talking about: one in `getInstance()`, one in `init()` that's printed and then dropped; and one in main. If you fix it with reference return, you'll still need to use references (initialized by `getInstance()`) to make it work.

Comment: I made a typo with the Shape, it is `static Shape& getInstance()`

Comment: @Star-lordX there are more "typos" in the code. Another one is `Shape singleton = Shape::getInstance();` also no reference but a copy

Comment: This was my issue! I was making copies, not references

Comment: @Star-lordX That's why a proper singleton has private constructors. Instead of a copy you'd get a compile error.

Comment: As of C++11 you can `delete` the copy constructor and assignment operator. This generally gives a better error message than a `private` copy constructor and assignment operator.